# NSPredicate to get entity of a relationship matching two conditions

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nspredicate

I am using `Core Data` to fetch entities. I need to fetch only entities that have a relationship `attribute` that has the ID of `41` AND that same `attribute` needs to have the `isOn` property set to YES.

Here is what I am trying:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(SELF IN %@ AND ANY attributes.attributeID.intValue == 41) AND (SELF IN %@ AND ALL attributes.isOn == %@)", self.places, self.places, @YES];
```

For some reason this crashes my app with not explanation.

Any ideas on if my predicate format is wrong?

**EDIT:**

Doing more research it seems I need to use `SUBQUERY` but not quite sure how in this case. Here is what I tried but it also crashes with a "cannot parse format" error:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(SELF IN %@, $e, $e.attributes.attributeID.intValue == %i && $e.attributes.isOn == %@).@count > 0)", self.places, 41, @YES]
```

Comment: What does "crash" mean? Do you have a stack trace?

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad No, no stack trace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Handle the `SELF IN` outside the subquery, since it relates to the entity being evaluated/fetched, not the related entity, and your SUBQUERY format is also a bit awry:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF IN %@ AND (SUBQUERY(attributes, $e, $e.attributeID.intValue == %i && $e.isOn == %@).@count > 0)", self.places, 41, @YES]
```

Also, I'm hoping your relationship name, `attributes`, is just for demonstration purposes in this question.  If not, I would recommend changing it.  It's really confusing to have a relationship named `attributes`: they are mutually exclusive concepts.